# Join character to columnar array

Tags: join, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I want to add a character ("~ ") to the front of each value of a columnar array, but every formula I've tried concatenates the values into a single cell rather than back to the column array.  Do I need to add `SPLIT`? What am I doing wrong?

This is what I've tried most recently

`=JOIN("~ ",FILTER(Categories!A2:A,LEN(Categories!A2:A)))`

`=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN("~ ",TRUE,Categories!A2:A))`

`=ArrayFormula(JOIN("~ ",{Categories!A2:A}))`

Ultimately, what I would like to see in a single column is:

```
~ Category 1

~ Category 2
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(Categories!A2:A<>"", "~ ♦"&Categories!A2:A, ), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Categories!A2:A<>"", "~ "&Categories!A2:A, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, player0!  I actually wanted the array to remain in a single column, so I adjusted your formula to
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(Categories!C2:C<>"", "~ "&Categories!C2:C, ), "♦")))`  If you want to edit your answer, I'll accept it.  Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you very much!  I like the simplicity of the second formula!  Much appreciated!